# magento 1.9.2.0 is not showing websecure url or baseurl

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.2.0 is not showing web-secure-url or baseurl even any path for %http:// % . Then, how I can move Magento website from local server to live server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento,basically save the site url in `core_config_data` table at database.

First,you need to check *`base unsecure url`* exit in that table by condition  like ***path='web/unsecure/base_url'***

also need to chec**k base secure url** exit in that table by condition   like ***path='web/secure/base_url'***.

If  ***this exit*** then you ***need update it value column by your  live site url***.

> UPDATE `core_config_data` SET value`='YOUR_SITE_URL'WHERE`
>   path`='web/unsecure/base_url'
>
> UPDATE `core_config_data` SET value`='YOUR_SITE_URL'WHERE`
>   path`='web/secure/base_url'

If  this not exit then you need insert at database by below query

> INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`,
>   `path`, `value`) VALUES ('', 'default', 0, 'web/unsecure/base_url',
>   'YOUR_LIVE_SITE_URL'), ('', 'default', 0, 'web/secure/base_url',
>   'YOUR_LIVE_SITE_URL);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly save the url from backend , then it will be visible in database.
It can be done via 
System-> configuration->general->web